# Render a rails object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a object 
`@user`
which as information about `@user.account` and `@user.address` 
How to render the whole `@user` object in json. Or how to render it in view. If I do `render json: @user` it only display user details. If I do `render @user.account` it display account details. But how can I render both at a time

**Ok I got it**

`render :json => @user, :methods => [:account, :address, :role]`

Comment: Try `render json: @user, :include => {:acount, :address}`

Comment: If you have the answer to your own question then post it as an answer - don't edit it into the question!

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will do so.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
render :json => @user.to_json(:include => {:acount, :address})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this

```
infos = []
@user.reflections.keys.each do |key|
  infos << @user.public_send(key).inspect
end
return render :text => infos.inspect // display all in browser
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution and it is
`render :json => @user, :methods => [:account, :address, :role]`